# Ubuntu 16.04 running very slow (system spec to blame?)

Tags: 16.04, performance

- Lenovo 100s 14"
- Memory 2 GB
- Processor Intel Celeron 1.6 GHZ x 2
- Graphics Intel HD Graphics (Cherryview)
- 64-bit

Any idea why Ubuntu 16.04 is running terribly slow on this system? I converted from Windows after believing in Ubuntu's speed. Now, I face this? I clean installed Ubuntu twice this week and did not add additional apps to it, but still no luck. Any suggestions?

[image: lshw output]

Comment: Usually very slow systems are a result of not utilizing the graphcis processor.  Can you run the command `sudo lshw -c video` and append the output of that command to your question?

Comment: I did so. You can click on the above link to see the image.

Comment: K - you are using the i915 driver, so that should not be the problem.  Have you used `top` or `htop` to monitor processes to see if one or more is consuming excessive amounts of processing time.

Comment: What exactly is running slow? A Celeron and two gigs of ram, provable without an ssd aren't the specs to run all programs fine. Usually you can find lighter alternatives (maybe starting with a different desktop environment, xfce or lxde)

Comment: Probably unrelated, but I had gnome-settings-daemon on top of my system monitor's process list consuming CPU resources after upgrading to 16.04. Changing the ownership of ~/.cache/dconf from root to back to my user with "chmod [my user].[my group] ~/.cache/dconf -R" fixed the issue and now my Ubuntu is running same as before the upgrade.

Comment: Could you please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814))? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer just has hardware with low performance. I don't think there's much you can do about it. You can however alleviate the situation by choosing a less resource-intense flavour of Ubuntu (or a different Linux distribution altogether). See [How do I find out which flavour of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](/q/206407/175814).